# Recovering time domain signal from sum of independent and identically distributed signals

Tags: fft, python, deconvolution

**Background**: I observe a sample of a variable `z` that is the sum of two independent and identically distributed variables `x` and `y`. I'm trying to recover the distribution of `x`, `y` (call it `f`) from the distribution of `z` (call it `g`), under the assumption that f is symmetric about zero. According to [Horowitz and Markatou (1996)](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2298119)  we have that the Fourier Transform of `f` is equal to `sqrt(|G|`), where `G` is the Fourier transform of `g`.

**Example**:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import gaussian_kde, laplace


# sample size
size = 10000
# Number of points to preform FFT on
N = 501
# Scale of the laplace rvs
scale = 3.0

# Test deconvolution
laplace_f = laplace(scale=scale)
x = laplace_f.rvs(size=size)
y = laplace_f.rvs(size=size)
z = x + y
t = np.linspace(-4 * scale, 4 * scale, size)
laplace_pdf = laplace_f.pdf(t)
t2 = np.linspace(-4 * scale, 4 * scale, N)

# Get density from z. Kind of cheating using gaussian
z_density = gaussian_kde(z)(t2)
z_density = (z_density + z_density[::-1]) / 2
z_density_half = z_density[:((N - 1) // 2) + 1]
ft_z_density = np.fft.hfft(z_density_half)
inv_fz_density = np.fft.ihfft(np.sqrt(np.abs(ft_z_density)))
inv_fz_density = np.r_[inv_fz_density, inv_fz_density[::-1][:-1]]
f_deconv_shifted = np.real(np.fft.fftshift(inv_fz_density))
f_deconv = np.real(inv_fz_density)

# Normalize to be a pdf
f_deconv_shifted /= f_deconv_shifted.mean()
f_deconv /= f_deconv.mean()

# Plot
plt.subplot(221)
plt.plot(t, laplace_pdf)
plt.title('laplace pdf')

plt.subplot(222)
plt.plot(t2, z_density)
plt.title("z density")

plt.subplot(223)
plt.plot(t2, f_deconv_shifted)
plt.title('Deconvolved with shift')

plt.subplot(224)
plt.plot(t2, f_deconv)
plt.title('Deconvolved without shift')

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Which results in
[image: output]

**Issue:** there's clearly something wrong here. I don't think I should need the shift, yet the shifted pdf seems to be closer to the truth. I suspect it has something to do with the domain of the IFFT changing with the sqrt(abs()) operation, but I'm really not sure.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because a cross-post on SO has already answered the question. **Please do not cross-post.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was given in a comment in [a cross-post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64213606/domain-of-inverse-fourier-transform-after-operation). I wasn't sure if it was a computational or conceptual issue I was having. Turns out it just an issue with the way FFT expects the input to be ordered and how the output is sorted.